# Are private members in javascript really that complicated?

Tags: javascript, private-members

I am trying to clarify my understanding of private members in Javascript. It seems like it should be easy:

```
function MyClass(param) {
  var thisIsPrivate = param;
  this.getPrivateMember = function() {
    return thisIsPrivate;
  }
}

var thing = new MyClass('tada!');

console.log(thing.thisIsPrivate)       // undefined
console.log(thing.getPrivateMember())  // "tada!"
```

In my reading, I keep coming across articles that don't even mention this as an option, but rather come up with complicated solutions like using closures or WeakMaps. Often the conclusion is that there is no good way to work with private members in Javascript.

Can anybody fill me in on what I'm missing? Is this a bad idea for some reason?

Comment: AFAIK this is a good solution. ES6 is missing this capability, even though it has some other syntactic sugar to appeal to developers used to OOP. In ES6's case, you'd have to use these more convoluted approaches.

Comment: Idk about you but this piece of code does look great and clean.

Comment: You **are** using a closure: the *getPrivateMember* function has a closure to *thisIsPrivate*. Perhaps read Douglas Crockford's [*Private Members in JavaScript*](https://crockford.com/javascript/private.html) from 2001. The technique was known before then, but his is a good early article.

Comment: RobG - this is true. I think I mindlessly mentioned closures without specific examples in mind. I guess the point is that the methods for storing the values become complicated rather than the methods for retrieving them.

Comment: Your class addresses the **private** aspect of the question, not the **member** indeed. How do you address 1/ member being accessed by other methods? 2/ prototype inheritance of member?

Comment: it's not really private if other class methods, including late-added methods, cannot reach the value. for what it is, it works fine for a lot of things, if's just not an "according to hoyle" private member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. So my understanding of the limitation of this approach is that methods added outside of the constructor cannot see the 'private' variables. I feel somewhat enlightened.

```
function MyClass(param) {
  var thisIsPrivate = param;
  this.getPrivateMember = function() {
    return thisIsPrivate;
  }
}

MyClass.prototype.showPrivateMember = function(){
  console.log(thisIsPrivate);
}

var thing = new MyClass('tada!');

console.log(thing.thisIsPrivate)       // undefined
console.log(thing.getPrivateMember())  // tada!

thing.showPrivateMember(); // ReferenceError: thisIsPrivate is not defined at MyClass.showPrivateMember

thing.showPrivateMember = function(){
  console.log(thisIsPrivate);
}

thing.showPrivateMember(); // ReferenceError: thisIsPrivate is not defined at MyClass.showPrivateMember
```